# How does trust in product compare to trust in quality process?

Tags: terminology

What factors determine trust in a product compared to trust in the quality process? I have seen reports with ticks and crosses in product trust and quality process columns, but I don't understand what the difference is or why they would be different.

I thought that trust in a product and trust in the quality process would be the same thing - if you trust the quality process, you trust that the product will be a quality product, and if you trust the product, the quality process must be good.

What makes these two types of trust different?

I want to understand which one I should use when.

Comment: Could you give more detail, and/or explain exactly what lead to the question?  Right now, this is probably going to be closed as too general, too opinion based, or unclear what you're asking.  For example, are you asking when to stop testing?  Or how much testing to plan for?  Or . . .

Comment: I reworded it but I still think its subjective and not a fair 'comparison' (both can be true, neither can be true, etc). so voting to close

Comment: @Michael Durrant -- That's why I posted "what does the quality is true mean?" under terminology. It is a genuine question that I have. Thx for rewording it a bit, appreciated. And yes similar questions arise for the quality is false and the quality is unknown. Is it "When perceived by senses as wanted/intended" that we can say "The quality is true"?

Comment: Thanks.  Ultimately I do not feel there is 'one' canonical answer that would apply to all.  I think the answer is situational and will always depend on many other factors.

Comment: It's a fantastic question - just not suitable for this site based on the way the site works

Comment: @Kevin McKenzie What lead to the question is seeing a check-mark (often colored green) or cross-mark (often colored red) to indicate results. Both for individual checks on the product/process as for results as a whole. Often without explanation what it is that makes it tick positive or not.

Comment: I'm going to try to edit this question in a way that will allow a canonical answer without losing what makes it such a fantastic question. If my edits don't work, feel free to revert them.

Comment: This can be change according to approach and quality criteria. There is good explanation of this situation in the ISTQ certification docs. You always define the quality processes and criteria, this make us Tester or QA. As a QA you are also responsible with documentation quality, software environment quality etc. because these are also defining the quality of product